# Can we use average as independent variable in regression to detect outlier?

Tags: regression, linear-model, interpretation, model, outliers

Suppose we have some data about earnings at different cities and different times, can I build a regression model:

$y = a + bx_1 + cx_2$

where $x_1$ is the median earning of the whole state, and $x_2$ is the ten days median in this city.

A high-level interpretation is that $b$ and $c$ account for the influence of location and time.

Then I plot residuals to check whether data are outliers.
Maybe I have other data (like GDP of the states) as x3 so I mix them together:

$y = a + bx_1 + cx_2 + dx_3 + ...$

Does my model look good? My main concern is that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are derived from the set of $y$ and I'm not sure whether we can reuse $x_1$ and $x_2$ to predict $y$.

Comment: The $y$ is "earning", specifically what?

Comment: Hi Nuclear03020704. That's just a term I made up to illustrate my example. For example, y could be the average earning in dollars per day in each city. Can I use the average earning of the state and average ten days earning in this city to build a regression model and find outliers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this might work. As long as $x_1$ and $x_2$ are not **perfectly correlated** with $y$, in which case no outliers will be spotted whatsoever.